# how to get list of TeX tree roots programatically in MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

Is there a way to get the list of all TeX tree roots from a command line?

I thought that `initexmf --show-config-value`  could do it, given that `miktex.ini` is supposed to include keys like `CommonRoots`, `OtherCommonRoots`, and `OtherUserRoots`, but I did not manage to find a syntax that would return a non-empty value (even if I have two custom TeX trees registered).
The `initexmf` shows the syntax as `--show-config-value=[SECTION]VALUENAME`, so I tried `initexmf --show-config-value=[Core]OtherUserRoots` and several variations thereof (with and without [], with dot, ..), but no luck.

As a side note, I did not manage to find `miktex.ini` on my system (Windows 10, user-based install) either...

Note: I originally wanted this to locate my global .bib file, so I can create .bib-files with only referenced papers using [bibfish](https://github.com/jwcarr/bibfish). In the meantime, I found that I can use `kpsewhich` for this, but it still irritates me that I did not find a way to make `initexmf --show-config-value` work...

Comment: I normally use `initexmf --report` if I want the list of roots. I'm not sure if the docu about miktex.ini is still up-to-date, `initexmf` seems to read the registry (where the roots are listed). You could open an issue at the miktex github about it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks, I have not noticed this option. Still, it would be nice to know if the `initexmf` command is broken or if I just don't know the correct syntax...

Comment: @MichalKaut  It is not broken as it works on my installation. Open an admin console to try it.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: What is the syntax to get the different tree roots then?

Comment: @MichalKaut same like Urlike suggested. `initexmf --report`.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: I know that this works, it does not even need admin console. I am asking for a working example of `initexmf --show-config-value`, preferably one that returns a TeX-tree root - but any example will do, just to show that this (sub)command works at all.